# Global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I define a global variable 'mode' right after the header of a page and before the code with all the javascript.

```
<?php require('header.php'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mode = ""; // flag to set to clicks to external site
</script>

<?php require('mainpage.php'); ?>
```

I have functions defined for in mainpage like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="channels.js"></script>
```

Then I access the global variable like this.

```
function channels() {
        if ( mode == "external" ) {
            continue;
        }
}
```

But this causes the script to crash.  Doesn't seem to know about the global variable.

How should I define that global variable to be accessed within a file.

Comment: What's that `continue;` doing there?

Comment: too few information, the crash has nothing to do with that global variable. Why are you using `continue` if no loop is inside your code?

Comment: What happens if `channel.js` gets loaded before `mode` is defined? Also, it's a very bad idea to use global variables. If you start to have a lot of javascript that interacts with other javascript in your application, you may want to look into [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: What do you mean "crash"? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.mode = "something";

function channels() {
    // window.mode 
}
```

Answer (score -5):

var - thats not the global variable. To define it don't use var

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    mode = ""; // flag to set to clicks to external site
</script>
```

Then **mode** will be a property of window object.

Comment: but why would that cause the script to crash? Btw, I didn't downvote this.

Comment: Even with the `var`, it will still be at the top level of the scope and available everywhere.